# header problem layout

Tags: css

I am trying to place the twiter and facebook icons on

http://trishtours.firstavenuedesigns.co.uk/ just below the trish tours logo but its not working can someone have a look at this for me I would be much apreciated for any suggestions could someone describe to me the css changes I would need to make all css can be viewed in chrome

Comment: Sorry, but this is pretty off-topic. Layout/design questions belong in a more appropriate area. This question isn't directly related to the configuration or code/customization of WordPress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Styles]

You see the inline-styles i uses for `a class="logo"` and `div#social`

[image: ScreenShot in FF with changes]

Answer (score 0):

This is not strictly a Wordpress problem, better for stackoverflow.com

Try adding these style:

```
#social {
   position: absolute;
   left: 21px;
   top: 54px;
}
```

to your style.css

I suggest to remove the white border from the images in the header

```
#header div img {
    border:none;
}
```